# How do I delete rows in a numpy array based on a single column?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array of floats, and I want to delete all rows in which the third column of that row contains a value less than `x`.

eg. `[[3,4,5],[3,3,8],[4,2,1],[1,2,1]]`, with threshold `2`, outputs `[[3,4,5],[3,3,8]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array([[3,4,5],[3,3,8],[4,2,1],[1,2,1]])
>>> x=x[x[:,2]>=2]
>>> x
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [3, 3, 8]])
```

Comment: upvoted..as a side note this works if there is a 2 in any column (if OP is interested): x[np.all(x>2,axis=1)]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[3,4,5],[3,3,8],[4,2,1],[1,2,1]])

threshold = 2

arr = np.array([row for row in arr if row[2] >= threshold])

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[3 4 5]
 [3 3 8]]
```

Alternatively, you can use `filter`:

```
np.array([*filter(lambda r : r[2] >= threshold, arr)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[3,4,5],[3,3,8],[4,2,1],[1,2,1]])
array = np.array([x for x in array if x[2] >  2])
print (array)
```